# Using List Comprehension with np.minimum to filter one of the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy-ndarray

- x = [list of positive numbers]
- y = [list of positive and negative numbers]

I want to use `x = np.minimum(x,y)` with the condition that if a number in y is negative then it assumes the value of zero such that the comparison in np.minimum returns 0 and not the negative number. I know I can do this in a loop but can I do it within a one line inside y[... expression ...].

I have tried lots of ways but I simply don't know how to write this as everything I do gets a syntax error.

Comment: `n.minimum(x, np.maximum(y,0))`

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  .... in your case the loop example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a minimum reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,3,5,6,8]
y = [-3,4,5,1,9,-8]
```

as commented by @Onyambu you have to call `np.minimum` twice:

if you just do np.minimum once then you will get negative numbers when they are minimum:

```
np.minimum(x, y)

#array([-3,  2,  3,  1,  6, -8])

x = np.minimum(x, np.maximum(y,0))
print(x)

#array([0, 2, 3, 1, 6, 0])
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but i believe that this will also be the fastest method.

Comment: Brilliant - I just never thought of that. Thx

Comment: @TimMountjoy can you accept the answer if it was useful